# Remove Vertical Spaces from list

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

I have tried many solutions from this site but none solve my issue, hence I decided to ask another question. Disclaimer: I know nothing about LaTex.

In my list, there is weird spacing after which the list starts which is really messing up, and induces confusion while reading.

Here is a picture

[image]

I want the bulleting to start from where is arrow is present.

Here is my code `.tex` part.

```
\twentyitemshort{Test}
{
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item test 1
\item test 2
\item test 3
\end{itemize}
}
```

Here is the `.cls` portion

```
\newcommand{\twentyitemshort}[2]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.70\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
    }\\
}
```

PS. I am using the twentyseconds resume template which can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/shivam-singhs-cv/nkfwzzfftmkd).
I have added `\usepackage{enumitem}` in my code apart from the original source code.

Here is my source code.

[template.tex](https://pastebin.com/9jnvDbie) file
[twentysecondcv.cls](https://pastebin.com/iLc8Zp0a) file

**EDIT 1**
I am attaching pictures of how it looks on my resume without using list and with list

Without list
[image]

With list
[image]

**EDIT 2**
I have attached the Minimal Working Code

1. [template.tex](https://pastebin.com/WVAQWsE9)
2. [resume.cls](https://pastebin.com/RcB8uZ4x)

**EDIT 3**
Please try using overleaf latex compiler, for some reason this code won't compile on some other latex compilers.

Comment: The comments conversation has been successfully finished it seems, accepted answer below, so I [moved it to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111067/discussion-on-question-by-abhay-patil-remove-vertical-spaces-from-list) for archiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are creating with the parbox is, that you change the baseline calculation after you started it. Therefore the alignment fails within the expansion. The simplest solution I can think of is using the attempt of @UlrikeFischer and move the `\bfseries` before starting the parbox, I also changed the width a bit. Put it somewhere before your `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\twentyitemshort}[2]{#1&\bfseries\parbox[t]{0.68\textwidth}{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname #2}\\}
\makeatother
```

As a result, the text will move up and will be properly aligned:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much TobiBS. This did solve my problem. But I have a doubt. Are `\makeatother` and `\makeatletter` necessary, because my code is compiling even if it is removed.

Comment: @AbhayPatik  Did you put it in the tex or in the cls file? In a class file it is not needed. And maybe it is not needed due to the csname/endcsname. But it does not hurt to keep them, neither does removing them has negative side effects.

Comment: I put them in the .tex file. In both the cases there is no difference. So I decided to keep them where they are. I think you tagged me wrong in your comment. It should be AbhayPatil and not AbhayPatik